# No horizontal lines enclosing a song in songs package

Tags: formatting, songs

The code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chorded,nomeasures,noshading]{songs}

\noversenumbers
\nosongnumbers

\renewcommand{\printchord}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\renewcommand{\extendprelude}{
    \showrefs{\it\normalsize\songauthors}\\
    {\bfseries
    \songcopyright
    \par}
}

\songcolumns{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Roses are red}[by={Antoine}]
\beginverse
    \[C]Roses are red \[G]and so are some wines
    \[C]I am already quite mad \[G]because I cannot remove the enclosing lines. 
\endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

So far, I was able to redefine some commands so that the output is
visually more appealing to me than the original one, but I am not
able to remove the horizontal lines enclosing the song.

In the documentation for the [songs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/songs), I was only able to find the probable reason for the lines (*The songs package was designed from the ground up to produce song books with many songs per page*).

In the `songs.sty` document, I have found three occurrences of `\hrule` and
by commenting out one of them, I can get rid of the line preceding the title.

Comment: A wonderful song ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\sbarheight` length controls how 'thick' the horizontal rules are; it is recommended on page 29 of the current `songs` package documentation, to use `\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}` to get rid of the horizontal rules completely.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chorded,nomeasures,noshading]{songs}

\noversenumbers
\nosongnumbers

\renewcommand{\printchord}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\extendprelude}{
    \showrefs{\itshape\normalsize\songauthors}\\
    {\bfseries
    \songcopyright
    \par}
}

\songcolumns{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Roses are red}[by={Antoine}]
\beginverse
    \[C]Roses are red \[G]and so are some wines
    \[C]I am already quite mad \[G]because I cannot remove the enclosing lines. 
\endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow, I have missed this. And I am also glad that you like the song:)

Comment: @Antoine: Sometimes it is very difficult to find the correct places. Writing Documentation is not as easy as it might appear on first glance.Sometimes you need a FAQ, others prefer a full reference and others require a fully documented and commented version of the package itself.